# Having trouble installing certain packages for R

Tags: r, package

I'm having trouble installing certain packages for R. I have now found this issue with jtools, sjplot, and sjmisc. What is strange about it is that it isn't with all packages, ggplot2 was installed fine as well as the devtools package.

I pasted the output below for trying to install sjplot.

This may just be a coincidence and a may be reading some of it wrong because I'm not very experienced with R, but the thing in common with those that dont work compared to those that don't is that they seem to be .tar.gz instead of .zip.
I see this both in the middle of this log and in the Temp\Rtmps96tec\downloaded_packages folder it spits out at the end. The folder shows previous package downloads and all the ones before these that I am trying now that I am having trouble with have been .zip's
Then in the log it looks like it looks for .zips and its fine, then it looks for .tar.gzs and after those is where the issue that keeps coming up happens, the
"'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." 
message. After that it doesn't look likr it does anything else successfully besides spit out the file int eh temp folder.

I'd love to be able to get it to work through R, but if there is a way to install manually since I have the .tar.gz downloaded and can just move the files over, but just moving the files that trying to reference library(sjplot) doesn't seem to work. I also tried installing with that tarball instead of the Repository but that didn't work either.

```
> install.packages("sjPlot")
also installing the dependencies ‘httpuv’, ‘later’, ‘prediction’, ‘shiny’, ‘emmeans’, ‘effects’, ‘ggeffects’, ‘merTools’, ‘modelr’, ‘sjlabelled’, ‘sjmisc’, ‘sjstats’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
             binary  source needs_compilation
httpuv        1.4.1 1.4.4.1              TRUE
later         0.7.1   0.7.3              TRUE
prediction    0.3.2   0.3.6             FALSE
shiny         1.0.5   1.1.0             FALSE
emmeans       1.1.3   1.2.1             FALSE
effects       4.0-1   4.0-2             FALSE
ggeffects     0.3.2   0.3.4             FALSE
merTools      0.3.0   0.4.1             FALSE
modelr        0.1.1   0.1.2             FALSE
sjlabelled    1.0.8  1.0.11             FALSE
sjmisc        2.7.1   2.7.3             FALSE
sjstats    0.14.2-3  0.15.0             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/httpuv_1.4.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1118480 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/later_0.7.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 605749 bytes (591 KB)
downloaded 591 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/sjPlot_2.4.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1054285 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

package ‘httpuv’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘later’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘sjPlot’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘prediction’, ‘shiny’, ‘emmeans’, ‘effects’, ‘ggeffects’, ‘merTools’, ‘modelr’, ‘sjlabelled’, ‘sjmisc’, ‘sjstats’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/prediction_0.3.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 34409 bytes (33 KB)
downloaded 33 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/shiny_1.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2350156 bytes (2.2 MB)
downloaded 2.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/emmeans_1.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 571200 bytes (557 KB)
downloaded 557 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/effects_4.0-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2021373 bytes (1.9 MB)
downloaded 1.9 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggeffects_0.3.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 239215 bytes (233 KB)
downloaded 233 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/merTools_0.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 476671 bytes (465 KB)
downloaded 465 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/modelr_0.1.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 118432 bytes (115 KB)
downloaded 115 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/sjlabelled_1.0.11.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 131062 bytes (127 KB)
downloaded 127 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/sjmisc_2.7.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 187915 bytes (183 KB)
downloaded 183 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/sjstats_0.15.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 339472 bytes (331 KB)
downloaded 331 KB

'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"E:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "E:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\library" C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec/downloaded_packages/prediction_0.3.6.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘prediction’ had non-zero exit status
'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"E:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "E:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\library" C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec/downloaded_packages/shiny_1.1.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status
'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"E:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "E:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\library" C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec/downloaded_packages/emmeans_1.2.1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘emmeans’ had non-zero exit status
'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"E:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "E:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\library" C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec/downloaded_packages/effects_4.0-2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘effects’ had non-zero exit status
'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"E:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "E:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\library" C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec/downloaded_packages/modelr_0.1.2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘modelr’ had non-zero exit status
'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"E:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "E:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\library" C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec/downloaded_packages/merTools_0.4.1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘merTools’ had non-zero exit status
'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"E:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "E:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\library" C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec/downloaded_packages/sjlabelled_1.0.11.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sjlabelled’ had non-zero exit status
'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"E:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "E:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\library" C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec/downloaded_packages/sjmisc_2.7.3.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sjmisc’ had non-zero exit status
'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"E:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "E:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\library" C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec/downloaded_packages/sjstats_0.15.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sjstats’ had non-zero exit status
'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"E:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "E:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\library" C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec/downloaded_packages/ggeffects_0.3.4.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggeffects’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec\downloaded_packages’
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit: I tried installing from the tools menu from the files in temp but got a similar error:

```
> install.packages("C:/Users/Coldzero/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmps96tec/downloaded_packages/sjstats_0.15.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"E:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "E:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\library" "C:/Users/Coldzero/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmps96tec/downloaded_packages/sjstats_0.15.0.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Coldzero/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmps96tec/downloaded_packages/sjstats_0.15.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I also tried using devtools to install straight from github:
install_github("strengejacke/sjPlot")

```
> install_github("strengejacke/sjPlot")
Downloading GitHub repo strengejacke/sjPlot@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/strengejacke/sjPlot/zipball/master
Installing sjPlot
Installing 1 package: arm
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/arm_1.10-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 219529 bytes (214 KB)
downloaded 214 KB

package ‘arm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec\downloaded_packages
Installing 1 package: effects

  There is a binary version available (and will be installed) but the source version is later:
        binary source
effects  4.0-1  4.0-2

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/effects_4.0-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1508494 bytes (1.4 MB)
downloaded 1.4 MB

package ‘effects’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec\downloaded_packages
Installing 1 package: ggeffects

  There is a binary version available (and will be installed) but the source version is later:
          binary source
ggeffects  0.3.2  0.3.4

also installing the dependencies ‘emmeans’, ‘modelr’, ‘prediction’, ‘sjlabelled’, ‘sjmisc’, ‘sjstats’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/emmeans_1.1.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1052492 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/modelr_0.1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 135311 bytes (132 KB)
downloaded 132 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/prediction_0.3.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 140872 bytes (137 KB)
downloaded 137 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/sjlabelled_1.0.8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 205033 bytes (200 KB)
downloaded 200 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/sjmisc_2.7.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 311847 bytes (304 KB)
downloaded 304 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/sjstats_0.14.2-3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 378915 bytes (370 KB)
downloaded 370 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/ggeffects_0.3.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 264629 bytes (258 KB)
downloaded 258 KB

package ‘emmeans’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘modelr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘prediction’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘sjlabelled’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘sjmisc’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘sjstats’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘ggeffects’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec\downloaded_packages
Installing 1 package: knitr
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/knitr_1.20.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 892099 bytes (871 KB)
downloaded 871 KB

package ‘knitr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec\downloaded_packages
Installing 1 package: lme4
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/lme4_1.1-17.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 5220055 bytes (5.0 MB)
downloaded 5.0 MB

package ‘lme4’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec\downloaded_packages
Skipping install of 'modelr' from a cran remote, the SHA1 (0.1.1) has not changed since last install.
  Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
Installing 1 package: psych

  There is a binary version available (and will be installed) but the source version is later:
       binary source
psych 1.8.3.3  1.8.4

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/psych_1.8.3.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 5388180 bytes (5.1 MB)
downloaded 5.1 MB

package ‘psych’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec\downloaded_packages
Installing 1 package: scales
also installing the dependency ‘viridisLite’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/viridisLite_0.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 56811 bytes (55 KB)
downloaded 55 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/scales_0.5.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 692819 bytes (676 KB)
downloaded 676 KB

package ‘viridisLite’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘scales’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Coldzero\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps96tec\downloaded_packages
Skipping install of 'sjlabelled' from a cran remote, the SHA1 (1.0.8) has not changed since last install.
  Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
Skipping install of 'sjmisc' from a cran remote, the SHA1 (2.7.1) has not changed since last install.
  Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
Skipping install of 'sjstats' from a cran remote, the SHA1 (0.14.2-3) has not changed since last install.
  Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
"E:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/Coldzero/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmps96tec/devtools42282da83eaa/strengejacke-sjPlot-87179d5" --library="E:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/library"  \
  --install-tests 

'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

Edit2:
I looked at the topic at github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1514. It was disabled for my E: drive but I enabled it, rebooted RStudio and I'm still having an issue for all three methods of installation. Still seems to be .tar.gz because I had a short moment of excitement when it worked for one of the dependencies in the folder that was a zip that I tried first.

Edit3:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.13.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.2.1         tidyr_0.8.0        splines_3.3.3      carData_3.0-1      modelr_0.1.1       assertthat_0.2.0   stats4_3.3.3       coin_1.2-2        
 [9] yaml_2.1.14        pillar_1.2.2       lattice_0.20-34    glue_1.2.0         digest_0.6.12      glmmTMB_0.2.0      snakecase_0.9.1    minqa_1.2.4       
[17] colorspace_1.3-2   sandwich_2.3-4     Matrix_1.2-8       survey_3.33-2      plyr_1.8.4         psych_1.8.3.3      pkgconfig_2.0.1    broom_0.4.4       
[25] haven_1.1.1        xtable_1.8-2       purrr_0.2.4        mvtnorm_1.0-7      scales_0.5.0       stringdist_0.9.4.7 lme4_1.1-17        emmeans_1.1.3     
[33] git2r_0.21.0       arm_1.10-1         tibble_1.4.2       effects_4.0-1      bayesplot_1.5.0    ggplot2_2.2.1      sjlabelled_1.0.8   TH.data_1.0-8     
[41] withr_2.1.2        TMB_1.7.13         nnet_7.3-12        lazyeval_0.2.0     cli_1.0.0          mnormt_1.5-5       survival_2.40-1    magrittr_1.5      
[49] crayon_1.3.4       memoise_1.1.0      estimability_1.3   nlme_3.1-131       MASS_7.3-47        forcats_0.3.0      foreign_0.8-67     tools_3.3.3       
[57] data.table_1.10.4  multcomp_1.4-8     stringr_1.2.0      munsell_0.4.3      prediction_0.3.2   bindrcpp_0.2.2     ggeffects_0.3.2    rlang_0.2.0       
[65] grid_3.3.3         nloptr_1.0.4       ggridges_0.5.0     rstudioapi_0.7     gtable_0.2.0       codetools_0.2-15   abind_1.4-5        sjstats_0.14.2-3  
[73] curl_2.4           reshape2_1.4.2     sjmisc_2.7.1       R6_2.2.0           zoo_1.8-0          pwr_1.2-2          knitr_1.20         dplyr_0.7.4       
[81] bindr_0.1.1        modeltools_0.2-21  stringi_1.1.5      parallel_3.3.3     Rcpp_0.12.16       lmtest_0.9-35      tidyselect_0.2.4   coda_0.19-1
```

Seems like that's an old version of R was trying to find the version earlier but only found the rstudio version then forgot I was looking for it...

Comment: Have you tried following the UI to manually install? Click on 'Tools', 'Install Packages', then under 'Install From', you can direct it to the `.zip` or `.tar.gz` file directly

Comment: Have you tried looking for the packages on GitHub and installing straight from there with `devtools`? I've had this problem only with R 3.5.0 packages... weird errors installing the usual way, lots of pulling hair out, then it works installing from GitHub.

Comment: @ADuv I did, I get a similar error: 'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"E:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "E:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\library" "C:/Users/Coldzero/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmps96tec/downloaded_packages/sjstats_0.15.0.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Coldzero/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmps96tec/downloaded_packages/sjstats_0.15.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: @mysteRious I tried that as well. It seems to run differently but eventually seems like it gets to the same place. The log is too long to post in a comment but in ends with the same "'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: You may want to edit your post instead of commenting to get back to us so others can chime in more easily. Did you check out this link? https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1514

Comment: Can you type `sessionInfo()` in the console and paste the results here?

Comment: One last thing: are you working on your own computer and drives, or are you parsing it through different networks / network drives entirely?

Comment: @JosephWood posted sessioninfo() output above 
@A Duv I am on my own computer and drives, no network drives.